# why java revert logical operators while compile

Tags: java

Actual java code is:

```
((rrd == null || !rrd) 
    && null != dam
    && null != dam.getac()
    && null != dam.getac().getc() 
    && null != sname 
    && sname.equalsIgnoreCase(dam.getac().getc()))
```

But when I look into class file it's:

```
((rrd != null) && (rrd.booleanValue())) 
    || ((((null == dam) 
    || (null == dam.getac()) 
    || (null == dam.getac().getc()) 
    || (null == sname) 
    || (!(sname.equalsIgnoreCase(dam.getac().getc()))))))
```

All `||` and `&&` interchanged.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Could you please add the following to the question: 1) at least approximate types of rrd, dam, sname; 2) the javap output, not your reverse-reverse engineered version. Thanks.

Comment: Because OR operations can be short-circuited.  The first OR that's true makes the whole logical operation true.  Also, you should **never** write such convoluted logical statements.  They're too convoluted for humans to understand.

Comment: Hi Koshinae, type of `rrd`, `dam`, and `sname` are `Boolean`, `java entity` and `String` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressions are not equivalent but inverted. It looks like the compiler avoids an outer (or implied) not here.

Note that short-circuiting is possible for both operations, `||` and `&&` -- in the first case when a true sub-expression is encountered and in the second case when a false sub-expression is encountered. So the ability to short-circuit alone does not explain this.

Answer (score 0):

See: [De Morgans Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

!A || !B == !(A && B)

Comment: I think OP knows that `!A || !B == !(A && B)`. The question however is **why** the compiler changes it to this.

Comment: Normally the compiler does such things to optimize the performance, because some operations can be executed faster than others.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to be an optimization -- I'd expect it to be that the decompiler the OP is using can't tell the difference, or that it compiles into exactly the same bytecode anyway.